# The eigenvector of a matrix is zero, or non-existant

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this matrix

\begin{bmatrix}1&7&3\\7&4&-5\\3&-5&6\end{bmatrix}

I found that its eigenvalues are :

> -7.008, 10.972, 7.036

when I use these eigenvalues to find eigenvectors by using

> (A-λI)X = 0

where X is the eigenvector, I reduce the matrix `(A-λI)` to the RRE form, and I always end up with Identity matrix or

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

which results in X being

\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}

which is not possible, so I tried using Wolfram Alpha and it did give me vectors when I saw the solution steps the program multiplied both sides of the equation by a matrix.

[This the solution for λ=7.03595](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4zWj.png)

what is the matrix and where did it come from?

I tried using [Symbolab](http://www.symbolab.com) but it said that there are no eigenvectors for `λ=-7.00793 and λ=10.97198`

Comment: @Moo alright I will rewrite my method of reducing the matrix and post it

Comment: I used http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/calculate.aspx and when I entered your matrix, it gave me nonzero vectors. The eigenvalues are "awful" so I suspect that if you want to do this algebraically, it won't look nice at all